# PHP Session scope

Tags: php, session

I have one `index.php` , `one.php` file.

In one.php i have starting the session and setting the session var:

```
session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_GET['user'];
    }
function getUsername(){
  return $_SESSION['user'];
}
```

Im including one.php in index.php after im calling the function  `getUsername()`
im not starting session in `index.php`

```
include_once('one.php');
echo getUsername();
```

But im not getting the session in `index.php`. Why ? im passing the the variable as

```
index.php?user=newuser .
```

is it not possible to get the session in all pages with out starting session . is it any possible method to get a global variable from any where, if i set it once..?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display. Put this at the very top of `index.php` after the opening `<?php` tag... `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. FYI, you must call `session_start()` before any output (HTML, whitespace, etc) is sent to the browser.

Comment: your code doesnt have any bug. It is perfect. I suppose that your problem is with session_start(). As Phil said call session_start() at the very beggining of one.php before any output. a single space can also make it not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to get the session in all pages without starting session. So basically, you need to follow either of the following two ways:-

- Start the session in very new page, at the very beginning of the page, without any whitespace characters, using these lines of code:-

`<?php`

`session_start();`

`// Other Lines of Code`

- Include another common page (`common.php`) which has the line (`session_start();` at the very beginning of that common page) at the beginning in every new page.

So basically, this particular statement (`session_start();`) is the heart of using the session.

Now according to your question, the page "`one.php`" must be included at the very beginning. So it should be working.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is global. But it will only be initialized once `session_start` is called.

Comment: Ok.. if i add session start in index.php and if i set the session in one.php without addig session start in one.php.. will it work..?Since im just including the one.php in index.php where session already starts..

Answer (score 0):

session_start() has to be added right after starting first PHP file.

- Make sure you do not have any whitespaces/characters before `<?php`
- Turn on error reporting (1)
- Try var_dump($_SESSION) (2)

(1):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

(2):

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start` as the first line in index.php. And it is not necessary to add in one.php since `$_SESSION` is global you can access the variable in one.php

Answer (score 0):

For every Session session_start() at the top would be essential

```
session_start()
```

Try with

```
print_r($_SESSION)
```

You can debug the all SESSION value.